# JSONArray from String

Tags: java, android, json

I have problem when I try to make JSON Array from String...

I have succeded to Send JSON from my WEB API.

I Got data from mongo, serialized it with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and post it in my android where I got it like a string, now when I want to:

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray(ThatString)
```

I have exception, in Log.D I see String that I got like this:

```
[{\"DatumPoruke\":\"2015-12-14T12:10:20.841Z\",\"Tekst\":\"posao 1\",\"FromUserid\":\"user\",\"ToUserid\":\"driver\",\"ChatId\":\"1\"},{\"DatumPoruke\":\"2015-12-14T12:10:24.077Z\",\"Tekst\":\"Prihvaceno\",\"FromUserid\":\"driver\",\"ToUserid\":\"user\",\"ChatId\":\"1\"}]
```

Those \ are from Log.d, they don't exist in real String.

I copied just two objects, I have it more...

BTW. I have one more error:
Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I put that method in runnable and started new thread but, still get error, at first was 69 frames now 39 in thread.

Comment: You need to more information about the kind of exception that you're getting while trying to parse that string

Comment: Share your json String that you got as a response from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this:

```
result = result.substring(1, result.length()-1);
result = result.replace("\\", "");
```

And now working good.

I  getting String with slashes and quotes in beggining and end. Don't know why, but this is not good solution doing it on client side. If anybody have experience with this - help.

Comment: What is `result`??

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to work with JSON in Android is to use `gson` library. With `gson`, your code should look something like that:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String [] myArray = gson.fromJson(myString, String[].class);
```

To add gson, modify your build.gradle and add a dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

or whichever level is the newest one

Comment: How to convert this to JSONArray?

Comment: How to convert what to JSONArray?

Comment: Probably, this was some time ago. Not really sure now how my answer related to the OP's question. Are you having a similar issue?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to correctly get a JSONArray from a String resource.

Comment: What sort of problem you're getting?

Comment: Posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187190/cannot-create-a-java-jsonarray-from-string?noredirect=1#comment60012902_36187190

Comment: maybe this will help: https://www.noom.com/company-blog/2015/07/android-local-unit-testing-part-1/

Comment: Indeed, testing JSON files with Junit is not straightforward.  Your link pointed me toward the right solution.  Thanks!