# Cannot create a Java JSONArray from String

Tags: java, android, json, java.util.scanner

I get a JSON string from a **File** like this:

> "[
>     {
>       "id": "eVgoHOU0000000011",
>       "network": {
>         "networkName": "EVgo"
>       },
>       "status": "Available",
>       "plugscore": 9,
>       "stationname": "Wholefoods Market",
>       "description": "Very dependable station next to store.",
>       "location": {
>         "latitude": 30.596481,
>         "longitude": -96.353554,
>         "address": {
>           "address1": "Golden Acres",
>           "address2": "second floor",
>           "city": "College Station",
>           "state": "TX",
>           "zipcode": "77029"
>         },
>         "description": "Map marker location is next to gas station."
>       },
>       "connectors": [
>         {
>           "type": "US Wall Outlet",
>           "power": "40 amp",
>           "status": "Uknown"
>         },
>         {
>           "type": "US Wall Outlet",
>           "power": "40 amp",
>           "status": "Uknown"
>         },
>         {
>           "type": "CHAdeMO",
>           "power": "40 amp",
>           "status": "Unavailable"
>         }
>       ],
>       "planName": "No Charge to Charge"
>     }]"

I'd like to convert it to a JSONArray like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
String json = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);`
```

However, the **array** object is always null.  What is wrong here?

**UPDATE**
Works correctly in my Android code when I use this:

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner( context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search));`

But it isn't working when I create my previous scanner from a File.  There must be something that the Android framework is doing correctly that Java isn't...

**UPDATE 2**
I have been able to isolate the problem.  It happens when I'm doing white-box testing of my Android application with Junit4.  So, I am constructing this new object class which has this helper method to create a JSONArray, and it doesn't get created during the junit run.  It gets created fine, though, in regular java code runtime.

Comment: Why did you use the delimiter '\\A'. I am googling for this regex, but I can not find it. Are you sure this regex is valid? I know '\A' means 'start of string'

Comment: Is your file valid JSON?

Comment: @JernejK It is a totally valid delimeter.  It matches only once in whole input, so Scanner.next returns whole InputStream as a String.

Comment: The code looks valid, but it is impossible for `array` to be `null` after construction. Either construction fails with an exception that you should catch and dump to get some insight, or you're getting a `JSONArray` object.

Comment: @szym What I'm getting in the debugger is `array = {JSONArray@902} "null"`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky can you paste the output of json instance, so that we really know it takes everything from the file. I know this will not solve the problem, but would be nice to know for sure from your example. And I would also add the try catch clause, to look for JSONException like it is pointed out in the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29). From looking the Java documentation it should transform the String value to JSONArray.

Comment: @JernejK You can see the json output here: http://pastie.org/10771557.

Comment: I saw from one of the example that using quotes " has to be like this \". Can you check if that is the problem? I am looking at this [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial) and the quotes are with backslash. Someone already pointed out that there are [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070173/android-parsing-json-string-inside-of-double-quotes) with quotes.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky what do you see in the debugger if you set `json = "[]";` before invoking `new JSONArray(json)` ?

Comment: @szym he pointed out that it contains the same string value as displayed above, before the code. I also asked him the same and he reassured me it contains that value.

Comment: @szym If I try your suggestion, I still get a null value in the array.

Comment: So the quotes are not the problem @IgorGanapolsky?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Then this could be an issue with the debugger or with `toString()`.  Check what you get with `int length = array.length()` when using your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got down to the bottom of this issue, and found a solution.  It turns out that Junit tests in Android do not have access to the Java JSON library.  They only have access to stubs (which throw exceptions by default).  So one must pull in the entire json library for tests:

```
testCompile 'org.json:json:20160212'
```

You can find the latest version number of json on maven central: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Answer (score 0):

If the file includes the outer double-quotes, then `new JSONArray(...)` will throw `JSONException`. If it does not, I see no problem here.

Technically a Java constructor cannot return `null`. Use a debugger to step through the code. You could be ignoring an uncaught exception.

Comment: You're right about the FileInputStream -- no need for it as `Scanner` accepts `File`.